# Как узнать версию установленного SQL сервера?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Добрый день, я знаю про SELECT @@VERSION, а есть другие способы?

Comment: а зачем другие если этот есть?

Comment: @heff, например, когда у вас нет доступа конект к SQL Server

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Есть 2 основных ситуации при получении версии Microsft SQL Server:

1. У вас есть возможность подключиться к серверу (через SSMS, sqlcmd или любой другой клиент)
2. У вас нет возможности подключиться к серверу, но есть доступ к серверу Windows (или Linux если это SQL Server 2017)

Рассмотрим сначала первый вариант.
Большая часть информации доступна и поддерживается в актуальном виде в отличной и крайне рекомендуемой к прочтению KB321185: [Определение версии, выпуска и уровня обновления системы SQL Server и ее компонентов](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/321185/how-to-determine-the-version--edition-and-update-level-of-sql-server-a)

1. Подключитесь к серверу через [SSMS](https://github.com/ktaranov/sqlserver-kit/tree/master/SSMS).
   После подключения в обозревателе объектов в нем будут отображаться сведения о выпуске (в скобках), наряду с именем пользователя, которое используется для подключения к конкретному экземпляру SQL Server.
   [image: SQL Server version in SSMS]
2. С помощью запроса: `SELECT @@VERSION;`. Пример вывода для последней на текущий момент версии SQL Server 2016 SP1 CU4 (подробнее о версиях и обновлениях SQL Server можно прочитать [здесь](https://github.com/ktaranov/sqlserver-kit/blob/master/SQL%20Server%20Version.md#frequently-used-terms-and-acronyms)):

   ```
   Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1-CU4) (KB4024305) – 13.0.4446.0 (X64)
       Jul 16 2017 18:08:49
       Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
       Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows …
   ```
3. Запрос работающий для всех версий SQL Server, начиная с 2000:

   ```
   SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS ProductVersion
        , SERVERPROPERTY('ProductLevel')   AS ProductLevel
        , SERVERPROPERTY('Edition')        AS Edition;
   ```
4. Расширенная версия со всеми возможными свойствами сервера (взята из замечательных диагностических запросов [Glenn Berry](https://github.com/ktaranov/sqlserver-kit/blob/master/Scripts/SQL%20Server%202017%20Diagnostic%20Information%20Queries.sql)), но некоторые параметры доступны только для последних версий SQL Server:

   ```
   SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('MachineName')                  AS [MachineName]
        , SERVERPROPERTY('ServerName')                   AS [ServerName]
        , SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceName')                 AS [Instance]
        , SERVERPROPERTY('IsClustered')                  AS [IsClustered]
        , SERVERPROPERTY('ComputerNamePhysicalNetBIOS')  AS [ComputerNamePhysicalNetBIOS]
        , SERVERPROPERTY('Edition')                      AS [Edition]
        , SERVERPROPERTY('ProductLevel')                 AS [ProductLevel]  -- What servicing branch (RTM/SP/CU)
        , SERVERPROPERTY('ProductUpdateLevel')           AS [ProductUpdateLevel]  -- Within a servicing branch, what CU# is applied
        , SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion')               AS [ProductVersion]
        , SERVERPROPERTY('ProductMajorVersion')          AS [ProductMajorVersion]
        , SERVERPROPERTY('ProductMinorVersion')          AS [ProductMinorVersion]
        , SERVERPROPERTY('ProductBuild')                 AS [ProductBuild]
        , SERVERPROPERTY('ProductBuildType')             AS [ProductBuildType]  -- Is this a GDR or OD hotfix (NULL if on a CU build)
        , SERVERPROPERTY('ProductUpdateReference')       AS [ProductUpdateReference] -- KB article number that is applicable for this build
        , SERVERPROPERTY('ProcessID')                    AS [ProcessID]
        , SERVERPROPERTY('Collation')                    AS [Collation]
        , SERVERPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled')          AS [IsFullTextInstalled]
        , SERVERPROPERTY('IsIntegratedSecurityOnly')     AS [IsIntegratedSecurityOnly]
        , SERVERPROPERTY('FilestreamConfiguredLevel')    AS [FilestreamConfiguredLevel]
        , SERVERPROPERTY('IsHadrEnabled')                AS [IsHadrEnabled]
        , SERVERPROPERTY('HadrManagerStatus')            AS [HadrManagerStatus]
        , SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceDefaultDataPath')      AS [InstanceDefaultDataPath]
        , SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceDefaultLogPath')       AS [InstanceDefaultLogPath]
        , SERVERPROPERTY('BuildClrVersion')              AS [Build CLR Version]
        , SERVERPROPERTY('IsXTPSupported')               AS [IsXTPSupported]
        , SERVERPROPERTY('IsPolybaseInstalled')          AS [IsPolybaseInstalled]  -- New for SQL Server 2016
        , SERVERPROPERTY('IsAdvancedAnalyticsInstalled') AS [IsRServicesInstalled]  -- New for SQL Server 2016
   ;
   ```
5. Начиная с выпуска SQL Server 2008, можно также использовать отчет об обнаруженных установленных компонентах SQL Server. Этот отчет можно найти на странице `Сервис -> Центра установки SQL Server`. Это средство отображает сведения обо всех экземплярах SQL Server, установленных в системе. К ним относятся клиентские средства, такие как SQL Server Management Studio. Единственное, о чем необходимо помнить: это средство может выполняться только локально, в системе, в которой установлен экземпляр SQL Server. Его нельзя использовать для получения сведений об удаленных серверах. Подробнее [здесь](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/petersad/2009/11/12/sql-server-2008-discovery-report/)

Теперь рассмотрим способы узнать версию для второго варианта когда у вас нет возможности (или прав) подключится к SQL Server:

1. `{InstanceHome}\MSSQL\Binn\sqlservr.exe -v [-s InstanceName]`

Если на сервере установлен только один инстанс SQL Server, то -s не нужен:

```
    C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Binn>sqlservr.exe -v
```

В противном случае необходимо указать название интересующего инстанса, например:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS2014\MSSQL\Binn>sqlservr.exe -v -s SQLEXPRESS2014
```

2. Если операционная система Windows, то можно проверить ветку реестра:

   ```
   Key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\{VersionNumber}\Tools\Setup
   Name: Edition
   ```

В командной строке cmd:

```
REG QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\{VersionNumber}\Tools\Setup" /v /e /f Edition
```

3. Через скрипт Powershell:

   ```
   $inst = (Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server').InstalledInstances
   foreach ($i in $inst){
       $p = (Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL').$i
       (Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\$p\Setup").Edition
       (Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\$p\Setup").Version
   }
   ```
4. Просмотрите первые несколько строк в файле журнала ошибок для данного экземпляра. По умолчанию журнал ошибок размещается в файлах `Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.n\MSSQL\LOG\ERRORLOG` и `ERRORLOG.n`.

За более детальной информацией можно обратиться сюда: [How do you find SQL Server version/edition without SSMS installed?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/67985/how-do-you-find-sql-server-version-edition-without-ssms-installed)

Answer (score 9):

Как вариант:

```
SELECT
SERVERPROPERTY('ProductLevel') AS ProductLevel,
SERVERPROPERTY('ProductUpdateLevel') AS ProductUpdateLevel,
SERVERPROPERTY('ProductBuildType') AS ProductBuildType,
SERVERPROPERTY('ProductUpdateReference') AS ProductUpdateReference,
SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS ProductVersion,
SERVERPROPERTY('ProductMajorVersion') AS ProductMajorVersion,
SERVERPROPERTY('ProductMinorVersion') AS ProductMinorVersion,
SERVERPROPERTY('ProductBuild') AS ProductBuild
```